# Remove information stored in App Groups

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, ios-app-group

I am having trouble removing information when a user logs out of my application since adding in the app group.

This is the code I am trying to use for it.

```
let appDomain = NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleIdentifier
let prefs = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: GlobalVars.suiteName)
prefs!.removePersistentDomainForName(appDomain!)
```

How ever when executed it doesn't remove any of the information from the App Group so the user remains logged in.

Any help would be appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
         NSUserDefaults(suiteName: GlobalVars.suiteName)!.removeObjectForKey("USERNAME")
         NSUserDefaults(suiteName: GlobalVars.suiteName)!.removeObjectForKey("ISLOGGEDIN")
         NSUserDefaults(suiteName: GlobalVars.suiteName)!.synchronize()
```

This solved my problem.

Comment: Actually in the question it's trying to delete all user defaults items. You can do it for user defaults items which have appgroup enabled by setting appgroup to app domain in `removePersistentDomainForName` call.